# Dependence of Noise Tolerance of waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, noise

Electromagnetic waves are used for transmission of any message. And different kinds of waves have different noise-tolerance. If my guess is right then the noise tolerance is a property of wave which tells us how much the wave can tolerate the disruption of message. However I am not sure

But on what factors does noise tolerance depend?

I need a simple answer for the high school course.

Edit: My doubt arises from the question:

> Which of the following modulated signal has the best noise-tolerance ?
>
> (A) short-wave
> (B) medium-wave
> (C) long-wave
> (D) amplitude-modulated

Comment: afaik, there's a huge amount of work on these topics, but no simply summary because the answer depends on the way in which the information is encoded: pulsed, AM, FM, the spectrum used and the nature of the noise, etc, etc.  "Shannon information theory" is the best I know for a generalized approach (and there are some nice summaries, eg, some Kahn academy lectures) but in general it's a complex topic.

Comment: @tom10 But my doubt arises from a question of exam conducted in the whole country. I don't think that they can just put such a complex thing in the paper. There must be a simple solution i hope.

Comment: tom10 is correct, but I am more troubled by the fact that this is not even close to high school material. Strictly speaking it's not even physics but either information theory or electrical engineering. Who asked you to write about this? The most simple answer, in terms of physics, is "signal to noise ration", but that's not even a fraction of the story.

Comment: @CuriousOne added the question

Comment: To be frank... that sounds ridiculously nonsensical.

Comment: @CuriousOne Why is that?

Comment: Why is the question "Which is prettier: 1) red 2) blue 3) green 4) round?" nonsensical? Well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37860/discussion-between-manshu-and-curiousone).